# Why does jQuery ajax (JSONP) work without `&callback=` but fails with `&callback=functionname`

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I need to do a JSONP call.

Ajax function call :

```
$.ajax({
    url: myPath,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("hello"); 
    }
});
```

getJSON function call :

```
$.getJSON(myPath + '&callback=prova?', function(data) {
    alert("hello");
});
```

with getJSON (using &callback=prova for setting JSONP protocol) I get an error 200. .ajax() works as well. Why? I want to use getJSON here...

Comment: The question mark at the end of the query string does not look right.

Comment: AFAIK the code 200 shouldn't be an error, [see here)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: Did you check at the server side that the same request is made in both cases? If it's your server, you should be able to find the URL in the logs, otherwise you can always resort to network sniffing.

Comment: @themarcuz when retrieving JSONP, you will sometimes see a 200 OK HTTP code for the request, yet the browser will give you an XSS error as it prevents the data being processed.

Comment: Oh, yes, 200 shouldn't be an error. Your sample does not include any check for status/error. Can you show your actual test code which does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `callback=?` and not `callback=prova?` if you want your request to be treated as JSONP:

```
$.getJSON(myPath + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    alert("hello");
});
​
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$.getJSON(myPath + '?callback=prova', function(data) {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work as jQuery uses its own custom callback name (which is unique and different each time an ajax function is called). It has to be "`&callback=?`" (which can be omitted actually, as jQuery will detect the different hostname and append `&callback=1` for you). jQuery will then replace the `?` with the correct callback function name.